# Error while installing Open Web Analytics

Tags: php, monolog, openwebanalytics

Getting the below error while installing Open Web Analytics.

Open Web Analytics - 1.7.8
Operating System : Windows 10
Wamp Server : PHP Version 8.0.26
MySQL 8.0.31
Apache 2.4.54.2

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Monolog\Logger" not found in C:\wamp64\www\owa\modules\base\classes\error.php on line 68

When i try to install Open Web Analytics i am getting the below error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Monolog\Logger" not found in C:\wamp64\www\owa\modules\base\classes\error.php on line 68

Can somebody help me to identify the issue